# Can't open .py file from Spyder after downloading Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

Even after looking through numerous topics about this matter, I have been unable to find a solution for my predicament.

I have recently downloaded Anaconda navigator v.1.7.0 from which I can use Spyder v3.2.6 has an IDE. I would like to open .py scripts from file explorer with Spyder has default, but when I go in ‘open with’ and click on spyder.exe in C:\Anaconda\Scripts, all I get is a black console window that closes instantaneously. Can anybody help me out on this matter?

I note that I can drag and drop .py files on the Spyder console directly, but has previously mentioned by other users, this feels a little awkward and cumbersome.

From [How to get Spyder to open python scripts (.py files) directly from Widows Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817046/how-to-get-spyder-to-open-python-scripts-py-files-directly-from-widows-explor), I have tried manipulating the spyder-script.py in regedit but to no avail.

This is a similar issue but doesn’t seem pertinent for the current case:  [WinPython Cannot run .py files directly (without spyder)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317029/winpython-cannot-run-py-files-directly-without-spyder)

These two threads precisely discuss about what I’m trying to do:

- [How to read a .py file after I install Anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39646077/how-to-read-a-py-file-after-i-install-anaconda) But no good answer
- [Set Spyder as default Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643474/set-spyder-as-default-python) and there are comments that talk about creating a spyder.dat file, but I have no idea on how to do this and I can’t find any proper documentation on it.

I also took a look at this: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/466 and this https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/971 but I can’t make sense of the exchanges

Could the answer be with the spyder.dat file? Or maybe with something else? That's what I'd like to know.

Cheers

Comment: have you tried running Spyder without Anaconda?  Just run Spyder from the command line.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) We added some changes that should fix this problem in our next version (**3.3.0**), to be released in a couple of weeks.